# UITableView:reloadSectionIndexTitles animated correct way

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am trying to hide the index bar of a `UITableView` while scrolling.

Therefore I am reloading the section index titles when I start scrolling and when finish. Returning an empty array hides the bar.

**My code is**:

```
var showSectionIndexTitles = true
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    showSectionIndexTitles = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadSectionIndexTitles()
    })
}

override func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    showSectionIndexTitles = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadSectionIndexTitles()
    })
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {
    if showSectionIndexTitles {
        return uniq([UITableViewIndexSearch] + AlphabetUppercase + datamanager.categoryIndexTitles)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This works when using no animations, but I would like to use an animation.
I would prefer an animation where the whole bar moves out to the right when the bar is hidden and move in from the right when the bar is visible

I tried to use `UIView:animateWithDuration` to test if an animation is possible at all.

**What I have noticed:**

- This basic animation moves/scales in from the left top corner when
  visible
- When hiding the bar it disappears instantly

**My questions:**

- What is the best way of achieving an animation for indexbar visibility?
- What is the best way of achieving the particular animation I mentioned earlier?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

I just remembered where I have seen this effect before: iOS 8.4 Music App

Apple does the same when you scroll so far that you can only see the title list(`UITableView`)

**EDIT 2:**

I filed a bug report to apple suggesting a function for changing visibility of the index bar with a `animated` parameter. I am going to inform you as soon as I get a response.

Even though @matt already suggested a possible solution in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32381425/3515302), still if anybody else knows a different convenient way of solving this problem or has also faced this kind of feature in the past I would be glad to hear from you!

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is unsupported. Therefore there is no "best" or "correct" way - whatever you do will be an illegal hack. What I would do is snapshot the index bar, hide the real index bar as you are already doing (i.e. legally and normally), and animate the snapshot.

Comment: Please read my answer. :) Your example is excellent, and I enjoyed playing with the animation by scrolling up and down, but it changes nothing. The fact that Apple can do something doesn't mean that there's a public API for doing it. Indeed, for all you know, they could be doing exactly what I suggested. If you physically grab the index bar and start moving it around, you're likely to run into trouble: hence my suggestion that you substitute a snapshot, over which you have complete control.

Comment: I read your answer and i might implement it this way, thank you. I just wanted to let you know I found an example

Comment: I liked the example! If you think Apple should expose what they are doing here so that you can do it easily, file a bug report.